# WordPress not working with .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Have been around the houses with this - have read many *htaccess* issues etc - and still can't seem to get this to work.

I have a WordPress site installed at `var/www`

I wanted to have a specific URL point to a specific page. Started by browsing some WordPress plugins. None of them worked so I just went straight to the source and started editing the `.htaccess` file in the root of the WordPress installation. This is where it started getting frustrating.

One of the many attempts at an `.htaccess` file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
Redirect 301 /redirect-me http://my-wordpress-site/?page_id=15
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

All attempts at a Redirect have resulted in 404 Not Found errors.

I have asserted the following things:

- Apache2 Rewrite Module is enabled
- `www-data` has both read and write access to the `.htaccess` file.
- `AllowOverride` is set to `All` in the `apache2.conf` file for the directory

Here's a big clue for you: swapping the last ReWrite rule within my `.htaccess` file does absolutely nothing to my WordPress site...

```
RewriteRule . /poo.php [L]
```

Any other suggestions for debugging a failing `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Do you have access to the error log of your Apache installation?

Comment: What surprises me is that nothing changes when you replace WP's main rule. Are you sure this is the one used by WP ?

Comment: @JustinIurman That's also what surprised me. The debugging was pretty desperate by that point. When you say 'used' by WordPress, if you mean: WordPress's recommended default rewrite rule, then yes. But it clearly isn't being 'used' at all.

Comment: @vicvicvic Unfortunately not - permissions on the server logs are pretty strict.

Comment: Sorry, i meant `used` (executed) by the *server* (htaccess enabled and located in good folder). You said: `Apache2 Rewrite Module is enabled`. But i think it is not, actually. That would explain why `Redirect` does not occur (your code will be executed **only** if `mod_rewrite` is enabled because of `IfModule` condition). To test it, try to put `Redirect 301` line **outside** of `IfModule` block condition

Comment: @JustinIurman ReWrite Module is definitely enabled. This `in_array('mod_rewrite',apache_get_modules())` returns TRUE when run.

Comment: Did you try what i said ? Then, you could test if `htaccess is well enabled (AllowOverride)` by putting some garbage in your htaccess (you should get a 500 error).

Comment: @JustinIurman I tried putting the redirect outside of the `<If>` parenthesis, which didn't make a difference. Was there more to your suggestion than this? Can you give me some example garbage which should throw errors?

Comment: As simple as it is, something random such as `riogueodfvjbirf`

Comment: @JustinIurman The file is clearly not being used. Putting garbage within `<If>` and outside wields no errors and no site meltdown.

Comment: Well you got your answer: htaccess files are not enabled (`AllowOverride` problem). Do you have direct access to apache configuration ?

Comment: @JustinIurman Yes, but as mentioned, my `apache2.conf` file has the appropriate configuration for this directory: `<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>`

Comment: Did you change allowoveride to All yourself? This appears to be apache 2.4 so it's none by default, so if you changed it did you restart apache?

Comment: @PanamaJack Yep, changed it myself and restarted Apache. Keep them coming :-)

Comment: @PanamaJack Hold up. The restart must've been a botched attempt - just restarted and appears to work. Apologies. Thanks everyone. If someone would like to summarise the events in an answer then I'll accept.

Comment: @shennan No problem I've worked at 2 hosting companies, so that is a common issue. :)

Comment: @PanamaJack It's annoying because I definitely ran the `service apache2 restart` command (Ubuntu), but it never finished executing...

Comment: @shennan I hear ya, it happens. I'm personally a Centos fan, but I've supported both. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make configuration changes such as `AllowOverride` in the config, make sure your do a restart on Apache2 so the changes become effective. Give that a shot.